# focus() won't work - query

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have some `input` field, and I call this in my `js` file

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('#input_id').focus(); });
```

but it doesn't launch. Even, when I launch it in my chrome console, I get no focus. How can it be

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: is the element id correct `input_id`

Comment: can you show your html code ?

Comment: Probable the input_id element doesn't exists. The focus() function works fine. Here is a jsfiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/74JZR/

Comment: Please check Js is loaded or not?

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes the id is correct

Comment: @GaneshPandhere I don't really get any error, the focus doesn't display

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez yes it works if I call `focus` from an `onclick` event , but if I call in my console (I added in my code the inputs of your fiddle, jsut for testing) `$('#input_id').focus()` I don't get anything

Comment: @user1611830 but it's jsfiddle problem. If you call if from your console it won't work because you are in another window. I tested it in my live webpage and works fine. I had to do it with delay ans set focus on the website:

window.setTimeout(function() { $('#input_id').focus(); }, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

This is working sample for a text input, just match with your page code and see what you are missing as compared to this.

I assume that you have referred jquery js already and any other jquery functions work well in your page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () 
{        
  $('#input_id').focus();
});       
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input_id"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In any case **please make sure that there is no js error in your page** as 
`$('#input_id').focus();` must work fine individually, so only thing looks wrong could be reference to jquery, else some js error before code reaches to .focus() call on input_id.

Also you can validate if on your page focus for the input working fine, for this keep `$('#input_id').focus();` in a script tag just before your body page ends/closes, 
to make sure input control, jquery reference are placed correctly and page has no js errors, if this way too focus doesn't work then something is wrong with any of these 3.